# WPF App 64bit , won't run at startup, same code on 32bit work

Tags: c#, wpf, startup

I use this code for long time for my 32bit WPF apps without any problem.
Now the first time I compile 64bit app, this startup class not work more.

There is some reason why not is working?
No error, I check the registry and key not is there.
I really appreciate any help, fix if needed, comment.

Thanks so much!!

```
public class StartUpManager
{
    public static void AddApplicationToCurrentUserStartup()
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey    ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue("My ApplicationStartUpDemo", "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"");
        }
    }

    public static void AddApplicationToAllUserStartup()
    {
        using (RegistryKey key =     Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue("My ApplicationStartUpDemo", "\"" +   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"");
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveApplicationFromCurrentUserStartup()
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.DeleteValue("My ApplicationStartUpDemo", false);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveApplicationFromAllUserStartup()
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.DeleteValue("My ApplicationStartUpDemo", false);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsUserAdministrator()
    {
        //bool value to hold our return value
        bool isAdmin;
        try
        {
            //get the currently logged in user
            WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
            isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            isAdmin = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isAdmin = false;
        }
        return isAdmin;
    }
}
```

Update1:  What I use is `AddApplicationToAllUserStartup()`

The key is created in

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Aplication won't start, is really strange.

Update2:
Well, is very clear there is another way to call to 64bit app and this code only work on 32bit.
I just create a clean wpf app, with this class, if i compile 64bit not work if I copile 32bit work perfect!

**Update 3, the solution!**
Dont askme why, but force to use 32bit registry make work ok.
**`"SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"`**

This is really strange, no idea why happen,but that is the fix and now my 64bit app start perfect!

If somebody have the proper answer to this issue I love to know why happen.
Fix:

```
      class StartUpManager
        {
           public static RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32); //Dont think is necesary, but just in case

    public static void AddApplicationToCurrentUserStartup()
    {

        using (key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {

            key.SetValue("My ApplicationStartUpDemo", "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"");
        }
    }

    public static void AddApplicationToAllUserStartup()
    {

        using ( key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue("My ApplicationStartUpDemo", "\"" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"");
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveApplicationFromCurrentUserStartup()
    {
        using (key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.DeleteValue("My ApplicationStartUpDemo", false);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveApplicationFromAllUserStartup()
    {
        using (key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.DeleteValue("My ApplicationStartUpDemo", false);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsUserAdministrator()
    {
        //bool value to hold our return value
        bool isAdmin;
        try
        {
            //get the currently logged in user
            WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
            isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            isAdmin = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isAdmin = false;
        }
        return isAdmin;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that do not work ? what kind of error are you getting ?

Comment: I update the info, anyway I answer here too.
No error, the key never not appear on the registry.

Comment: Debug it, or check Windows event log. Both should tell what crashed the process and then you know what to fix.

Comment: No errors on code execution,  no errors on windows logs. ;(

Comment: Finally fixed, no idea why happen, but after make some test finally work.
Already update info with the fix.